# Three js add object to scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working off an example from the site and would like to add a [textured cube](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_cube) to the scene and ideally have it in a specific position. This is what I've tried so far but it's not appearing:

```
var frametexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/crate.gif' );
var artwork = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 200, 200, 20 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: frametexture } );
artframe = new THREE.Mesh( artwork, frametexture );
scene.add( artframe );
artwork.scale( - 1, 1, 1 );
```

Here's my [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vLjaoobn/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var frametexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/crate.gif' );
```

Should instead be

```
var frametexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/crate.gif' );
```

and

```
artframe = new THREE.Mesh( artwork, frametexture );
```

needs to be

```
artframe = new THREE.Mesh( artwork, material);
```

Comment: what errors did you get? it worked for me, here's a fiddle of it working:
https://jsfiddle.net/05nztq3y/1/

Note that I also changed the properties in the `BoxBufferGeometry` to be 200, 200, 200 so that it's a box shape instead